# Save result of XSQL query to a file in Java

Tags: java, oracle

I want to Save result of an XSQL query to a file using Java.

Does any one know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle document on [Using XSQL in Java Programs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14252/adx_j_xsqlpub.htm#CHEDEEFA) has instructions on how to call an XSQL from Java and get the result as an `XMLDocument` or send it to a `PrintWriter` or `OutputStream`.  There's a short example program there that sends the result to System.out, but it could be easily modified to send it to a file.